# Invoke SolidColorBrush

Tags: c#

How could I invoke so I won't get the following error?

> System.InvalidOperationException:

**The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.**

```
 // Method 1
                    if (((SolidColorBrush)RRefresh.Fill).Color == CustomGreen.Color && Foldername == string.Empty)
                    {
                        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                        {
                            Driver.Navigate().Refresh();
                        }));
                    }

// Method 2
        if (Driver != null && ((SolidColorBrush)RRefresh.Fill).Color == CustomGreen.Color)
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                Driver.Navigate().Refresh();
            }));
        }
```

Comment: Wrap it in Application.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [control.Dispatcher.CheckAccess()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.checkaccess(v=vs.110).aspx) to check whether the current thread owns the control. If it does own it.
Otherwise use this method:

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    ...// your code here.
});
```